# SonarQube with ant is failing

Tags: sonarqube

I have following set up:

- SonarQube Server 4.5.4
- SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.2 (Upgraded as 2.1 saying noSuchMethod)

And I am getting following error , though previously it used to work like charm with sonar-ant-task-2.1

```
D:\XXXXXXX\build-common.xml:90: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported since v4.2. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/api-changes.html**
        at org.sonar.api.resources.JavaFile.unsupported(JavaFile.java:118)
        at org.sonar.api.resources.JavaFile.fromRelativePath(JavaFile.java:106)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSourceImporter.parseDirs(JavaSourceImporter.java:69)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSourceImporter.analyse(JavaSourceImporter.java:63)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSourceImporter.analyse(JavaSourceImporter.java:59)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell which version of the Java plugin you are using?

Comment: It's sonar-java-plugin-1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the Java plugin that you are using (1.4) is very old and is definitely not compatible with SonarQube 4.5.4.

Please check the [Plugin Matrix](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+version+matrix), you will see that you should be using version 3.3 of the Java plugin.